# Attaching event handlers to Iframe if javascript is in Iframe itself

Tags: javascript, events

My Javascript is in Iframe itself.I tried to attach the keypress,mousemove,onclick,scroll,resized event handlers to attach event handlers to document.body but it doesn't seeme to work.For cross domain Iframes this code doesn't seem to work.I tried to attach it to window as well.Can you guyz point me to the problem.
Thanks
Swaraj

```
function click(e)
{
  e = e || event
   var target = e.target || e.srcElement
   cs_flag.isClicked = 1;
   console.log("IsClicked"+cs_flag.isClicked);
   console.log(getResult());
}
try{
window.parent.document.body.onclick = click(evt);


}
catch(e){
document.body.onclick = click(evt);

 }
```

Comment: You need Event Delegation

Comment: @DaveJust Can you elaborate with respect to code with a small code snippet.By delegation you mean addEventListeners and attachEvent right.But that won't solve the problem of the element to which they are attached.Thanks Swaraj

Comment: http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate

Comment: @DaveJust I have to use attachEvent for IE.But are you sure that would solve my problem for cross domain iframes.